# ¿Cómo mostrar la contraseña en asteriscos en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-requests

mi duda es la siguiente, en un curso que estoy realizando, en uno de los ejercicios se pide lo siguiente: "Cuando se termine la compra. Debe mostrar por pantalla el
usuario, la contraseña con * , y la lista de motos que pidió, más el
monto total de la compra."
La duda que tengo es como lograr eso en python, soy muy inexperto y no encuentro soluciones mas que importar getpass (que no se utilizarlo muy bien)

Esto es lo que pude escribir de código por mi cuenta:

```
import getpass
print("Para poder realizar una compra en nuestra concesionaria ingrese su usuario (mas de 4 caracteres y menos de 12) y su contraseña (mínimo 6 caracteres")

usuarui = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")
contrasena = getpass(input("Contraseña: "))
#for i in contrasena:
    #print("*")
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Solucion trivial, agarras el tamaño en caracteres de la contraseña y muestras tantos * como tenga la contraseña....

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo de como usar la librería getpass, no es necesario utilizar el input ya que el propio modulo pide al usuario lo indicado:

```
import getpass

try:
    p = getpass.getpass()
except Exception as err:
    print('ERROR:', err)
else:
    print('You entered:', p)
```

Ejecutando el código tendríamos la siguiente salida:

```
$ python3 getpass_defaults.py

Password:
You entered: sekret
```

Para imprimir la cadena tecleada con puros asteriscos se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
import getpass

try:
    p = getpass.getpass()
except Exception as err:
    print('ERROR:', err)
else:
    for i in p:
        print ('*', end='')
```

Para tener lo siguiente:

```
$ python3 getpass_defaults.py

Password:
You entered: ******
```

En esta pagina podrás encontrar más información sobre la librería:
https://rico-schmidt.name/pymotw-3/getpass/index.html